# How to represent $\log(2)$ as series with help of power serie of complex logarithm?

Tags: complex-analysis

I can write $\log (z)$ as power serie: $\log z=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{nz_0^n}(z-z_0)^n $. How to get from it $\log(2)$?

Comment: Put $z_0=1$ and $z=2$.

Comment: To avoid issues of convergence, use $$\log2=-\log\left(1-\frac12\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n2^n}$$ (Oh, and this question should be closed for lack of context, coming from a repeating, deliberate, offender.)

Answer (score 2):

Use $z_0=1$ and evaluate at $2$ to get

$$\ln 2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}(1^k)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$$

Comment: Sorry, I cant follow how excatly you got ln2. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}(z-1)^k $ What is the next step, after this?

Comment: Plug in $z=1$ .

Comment: Do you mean $z_0$?

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(z-z_0)^k}{kz_0^k}$ converges on the open disk $|z-z_0|<|z_0|$ and represents the complex logarithm on the principal branch $-\pi<\arg(z/z_0)\le \pi$.  Hence, we can write

$$\log(z/z_0)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(z-z_0)^k}{kz_0^k} \tag 1$$

for $|z-z_0|<|z_0|$.

The series in $(1)$ diverges outside of the closed disk $|z-z_0|\le |z_0|$.  Convergence on the boundary $|z-z_0|=|z_0|$ can be analyzed separately.

---

For $z_0=1$, and $z\in \mathbb{R}$, $(1)$ becomes

$$\log(x) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(x-1)^k}{k} \tag 2$$

for $x\in (0,2]$.

Then, we can represent $\log(2)$ using $(2)$ with $x=2$ and write

$$\log(2)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(2-1)^k}{k\,(1)^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$